# Testing Jersey endpoints with members annotated with springs @Value

Tags: java, spring, jersey, jersey-test-framework

I'm trying to use Jersey and it's integration with Spring, in order to have jax-rs endpoints in our spring web-app.

The problem I have is that members of the application that are annotated with @Value isn't populated in our unit tests.

The ones that are populated with @Autowired works fine, and if I create a setter method for the string and annotate that with @Value that also works.

What annoys me is that members annotated directly with @Value doesn't work in the test, but work when deployed in our tomcat.

Is this a problem with our test configuration somehow? Or is this a known issue somewhere?

These are the relevant dependencies I think:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-core</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-jetty</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

A small project that examplifies the problem here:
https://github.com/alexanderkjall/jersey-jetty-interaction-example/blob/master/src/main/java/no/hackeriet/bugs/SpringRequestResource.java

Comment: can you add some relevant code?

Comment: I can't really share the codebase from work, but I reproduced the issue here: https://github.com/alexanderkjall/jersey-jetty-interaction-example/blob/master/src/main/java/no/hackeriet/bugs/SpringRequestResource.java
I guess it's intended behavior, but I don't understand why
(run the code with 'mvn jetty:run')

Comment: starting to wonder if this is a bug

Comment: Is this a bug, you can use mockito to mock your objects , and do the unit tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be you might be missing component-scan, After adding  it worked fine for me.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="no.hackeriet.bugs" />
```

but I am not sure how it still worked in tomcat without component-scan, which quite puzzles me.

Comment: I figured that out also, I would prefer to not use component-scan in my unit tests, as I would like to have explicit control over the context in the test.

I opened an issue about this in jersey here: https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-3183